# Issues with RQuantLib advance date function

Tags: r

I'm relatively new to R and have found to SO invaluable to my coding journey, so first off: **thank you to all contributors**!

I'm writing some code looking at options trading, but I'm having issues with some of the RQuantLib functions.  I am trying to 'add' days to a date using the "UnitedStates/NYSE" calendar.  If you run the code below you can see the value is not as expected from the businessDaysBetween function (note the dates and the number of days returned or as an argument):

```
library(RQuantLib)

# This shows there is only one business day between the dates using the "UnitedStates/NYSE" calendar
businessDaysBetween(calendar = "UnitedStates/NYSE", from = as.Date("2010-06-20"), to = as.Date("2010-06-22"))

# And this next line of code should advance the date to "2010-06-22" but doesn't...
advance(calendar = "UnitedStates/NYSE", dates = as.Date("2010-06-20"), n = 1, timeUnit = 0)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated as it's doing my nut in!

Best,

L

Comment: you can add your solution as an answer as well (not as an edit to question)

Answer (score 0):

OK, so not a great start for me. I realised what the issue is: *advance* moves to the first business day after the date you supply if it is not a business day.

I wrote the following function to do that if it's useful. If anyone else knows a better way around this, please let us know!

```
GenerateClosestBusinessDay <- function(date) {
  d <- 0
  repeat {
    if (isBusinessDay(calendar = cal, dates = as.Date(date + d))) {
      return(as.Date(date + d))
      break
    } else {
      d <- d + 1
    }
  }
}
```